# Why is my integration test failing while application works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have this integration test that controls that a logged in user can't edit another user's data. 
The code is mostly from Hartl's RoR tutorial.
Those 2 tests fail but when I test myself, the application is behaving as expected (I can't open the edit page of another user)

When I run rake, I get (lines 31 & 38 are assert `flash.empty?`):

```
 FAIL["test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", UsersControllerTest, 2015-07-24 12:15:07 +0800]
 test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (1437711307.70s)
        Failed assertion, no message given.
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

 FAIL["test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", UsersControllerTest, 2015-07-24 12:15:07 +0800]
 test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (1437711307.71s)
        Failed assertion, no message given.
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:38:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

Then, if I comment out `assert flash.empty?`, I get this (lines 32 & 39 are `assert_redirected_to root_url`):

```
 FAIL["test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", UsersControllerTest, 2015-07-24 12:15:08 +0800]
 test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (1437711308.02s)
        Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/login>.
        Expected "http://test.host/" to be === "http://test.host/login".
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:39:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

 FAIL["test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", UsersControllerTest, 2015-07-24 12:15:08 +0800]
 test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (1437711308.03s)
        Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/login>.
        Expected "http://test.host/" to be === "http://test.host/login".
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:32:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

users_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

    def setup
        @user = users(:guillaume)
        @other_user = users(:peter)
    end

    ## other tests ##

  test "should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user" do 
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    get :edit, id: @user 
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when logged in as wrong user" do 
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    patch :update, id: @user, user: {name: @user.name, email: @user.email}
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
```

the lines that fail are the assert and assert_redirect lines

test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/reporters'
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Logs in a test user
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password = options[:password]   ||  'password'
    if integration_test?
        post login_path, session: {email: user.email,
                                   password: password}
    else
        session[:user] = user.id 
    end
  end

  private

  # Return true inside an integration test
  def integration_test?
    defined?(post_via_redirect)
  end

end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    before_action :logged_in_user,  only: [:edit, :update]
    before_action :correct_user,    only: [:edit, :update]

    ## new and create methods here ##

    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
            flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
            redirect_to @user
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    private

        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:name, 
                                         :email,
                                         :club_id,
                                         :access_key, 
                                         :password,
                                         :password_confirmation)
        end

        ## Before filters ##

        # Confirms a logged-in user
        def logged_in_user
            unless logged_in?
                flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
                redirect_to login_url
            end
        end

        # Confirms a correct user
        def correct_user
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
            redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
        end
end
```

users.yml

```
guillaume:
    name: Guillaume
    email: guillaume@example.com
    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

peter:
    name: Peter
    email: peter@example.com
    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

I went though the code several times but I can't find what's missing.
This is also the first app I'm trying to develop on my own, so for this part, I'm working from Hartl's rails tutorial material.

Comment: The last two asserts are failing in "should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user"?  Please make where the error is occurring as clear as possible.  If so, two ideas - confirm whether or not the `log_in_as` helper is working as expected and find out what flash message you are getting.  The first could be your issue, and, if not, the second should give you an idea what is actually happening in the test.

Comment: I added a assert `is_logged_in?` line after the call to `log_in_as`.  The line passes the test. I Don't know how to get the content of the flash message.

Comment: If you know which flash key is populated, just add a test like `assert_equal 'no match', flash[:danger]`.  This will fail but should show what is on the page.  Based on the error you are getting, it looks like your user is not getting logged in and you should see flash[:danger]='Please log in.'.  One you can confirm that, we just need to figure out why...

Comment: I didn't see clear when I tried `assert is_logged_in?`. The error message mentioned `Failed assertion, no message given.` so I thought the `is_logged_in?` assertion passed. Actually, it didn't. The problem was in the `log_in_as` helper. I was missing the `_id` in `session[:user_id] = user.id`. Thank you for your help. You put me on the right track.

Comment: Glad to help my friend!